# Search Student in File

Tags: java, api, file-io

I would like to search in an input file for `Student`s. Here is an overview of my work so far.

`Class Student`, with setters, getters and a display method (print)

`Class StudentFile`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StudentFile {

public void Trouver(int id) 
    {
        try
        {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Akram/Documents/akram.txt");
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;
         while((str=read.readLine())!=null)
         {
            Student s;

            if(s.getId()==id)
                System.out.println(s.print());
         }
         read.close();
            }
        catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}
```

This method display nothing, and I'm not sure why. Do you have any insight?

Comment: What does your input file looks like??

Comment: This code won't even compile.

Comment: We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading lines from the file and assigning its content to `str`, but you never do something with this value.

Also, `Student` seems to be empty.

Supposing your file includes only the ID of the student:

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String str;
     while((str=read.readLine())!=null)
     {
        // Your constructor assigns str to ID property of Student
        // Casting to Integer, because ID is a number
        Student s = new Student(Integer.valueOf(str)); 

        if(s.getId()==id)
            System.out.println(s.print());
     }
```

Also, make sure your `print()` method in Student really prints what you want.